# XML flattening with PIG : Nested loops and parent node access

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I am currently trying to loop on nested XML elements using XPath inside a PIG script and I face some limitations. Here is a dummy example of what I try to do :

I have an XML file looking like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Log CPEID="1847671824" CUID="0" >
    <Event EventTime="2015-10-14T21:50:00">
        <Action>A</Action>
    </Event>
    <Event EventTime="2015-10-14T22:55:12">
        <Action>B</Action>
    </Event>
    <Event EventTime="2015-10-14T23:54:51">
        <Action>C</Action>
    </Event>
</Log>
```

I want to output the following result :

```
   CUID    |    CPEID    |      EventTime       |  Action
---------------------------------------------------------------
123456789  | 56431284132 | 2015-10-14T21:50:00  |    A
123456789  | 56431284132 | 2015-10-14T22:55:12  |    B
123456789  | 56431284132 | 2015-10-14T23:54:51  |    C
```

If I load the XML file using the "Log" element in the loader (see under), I cannot loop on the "Event" element.

```
REGISTER 'piggybank.jar';
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

ALL_XMLs = LOAD 'test.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Log') as (x:chararray);
```

And if I load the XML File using the "Event" element, I cannot access the parent element. (Normal case following XMLLoader output)

```
ALL_XMLs = LOAD 'test.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Element') as (x:chararray);
```

Do anyone already faced the same problem and have an idea to process this example properly ? I know that UDFs could help me but, considering that this has to be easy to maintain, I'd prefer to use Pig / Hive only, if possible of course.

My Pig script, accessing only the first "Event" element (loop on "Log" element):

```
REGISTER 'piggybank.jar';
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

ALL_XMLs = LOAD 'test.xml'
using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Log') as (x:chararray);

Logs = FOREACH ALL_XMLs GENERATE
XPath(x, 'Log/@CUID'),
XPath(x, 'Log/@CPEID'),
XPath(x, 'Log/Event/@EventTime'),
XPath(x, 'Log/Event/Action');

DUMP Logs;
```

Result (not what I want... see above):

```
0;1847671824;2015-10-14T21:50:00;A
```

Comment: AFAIK this can be achieved with XSLT, not with plain XPath => download the XML file on a Linux box, run `xsltproc` on it, use Pig for post-processing.

Comment: Or, if you know somehow that you can have at most 3 items, generate two arrays for "EventTime" and "Action" and explode them afterwards, with sthg like `concat(Log/Event[1]/@EventTime, ":", Log/Event[2]/@EventTime, ":", Log/Event[3]/@EventTime)` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, confirming my conclusions. As mentionned, this transformation has to be easy to maintain and preferably using tools included in a classical hadoop distribution direclty, if possible of course. The fastest solution now is using Talend (with a XML parser) to flatten the XML File and then copy the .csv to the hadoop cluster. The number of Event is unbounded, so, impossible to use the second option. For info, I have to process 5 billions files per day, total size approximately 10Go.

Comment: 5 billion microscopic files per day - sounds like you need a *streaming* solution, not a *batch* solution like Pig or Hive. And Talend is by no means a "classical" Hadoop tool, whereas Storm and Spark (and Kafka as well) are included in Hadoop distros nowadays...

Comment: I totally agree with you. We are currently trying several solutions.. One of those is first to concat 1000 xml files into one big file, and process larger files, in batch mode. Our processing time is about 55sec for 500.000 files grouped in 1000 files per "big file". Streaming is the next step.